# Building non-overlapping adjacent isochrone (aka service area) polygons

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I'd like to write a function for building "optimal" disjoint adjacent isochrone polygons that "meet" each other at points from which the travel time by graph is equal to two respective neighbouring startpoints.

When you build separate isochrones from two points that are close to each other, resulting polygons overlap (or - if you specify that - merge with each other along the time break isoline), but I would like for the polygons to "meet" and stop, remaining adjacent, but not overlapping; sort of like Voronoi polygons, but with graphs instead of Euclidian space, so to say.

the [ArcGIS documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) says their GIS has this functionality:
[picture of non-overlapping isochrone polygons between pairs of cities Philadelphia-Charlotte and Chicago-Topeka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOsxe.png)

I'm trying to do the same in Python in following steps:

- declare two starting points for isochrones
- load a pedestrian graph via osmnx
- draw connectors from the points to the nearest point on the edge with networkx
- build an ego_graph from the starting points in osmnx
- find overlapping sets of edges (belonging to ego_graph of both startpoints) and assign each edge to the point to which the edge is closest:

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

# Step 1: Define store_locations and center_point
store_locations = [(47.293834, 39.704100), (47.2960449, 39.7140020)]
center_point = (47.295001, 39.709430)

# Step 2: Load graph
graph = ox.graph_from_point(center_point, dist=3000, network_type='walk')
print("Step 2 finished.")

# Step 3: Plot loaded graph
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph, show=False, close=False, edge_color='gray', node_color='w', edge_linewidth=0.5, figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title("Loaded Graph")
plt.show()
print("Step 3 finished.")

# Step 4: Create a connector for each startpoint
connectors = []
for store_location in store_locations:
    print(f'{store_location = }')
    nearest_edges = ox.distance.nearest_edges(graph, store_location[1], store_location[0])
    print(f'{nearest_edges = }')
    nearest_edge = nearest_edges[0]
    # print(f'{nearest_edge = }')
    print(f'{graph.edges.get(nearest_edges) = }')
    nearest_edge_coords = graph.edges[nearest_edges]['geometry'].coords
    connector_line = LineString(nearest_edge_coords)
    connectors.append(connector_line)
```

That said, I have 3 questions to the members of the community:

1. I don't know graph objects enough to be able to debug the step 4 (declaring the `nearest_edges` variable): I seem to be either not finding nearest edges or not referring to them on a 'larger graph' properly. Can anyone help me do that?
2. is there a more elegant / computationally cheaper way of solving the problem? it seems to me that this problem should be of interest not only to me and the ArcGIS engineers, but I couldn't find anything on google
3. does anyone have any hypotheses about what method is used to make the isochrones on the example isochrones made in ArcGIS? it's definitely not dijkstra + alphashape (I'm assuming that based on widely varying distances between polygons' vertices) and definitely not [raster cost-based](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.cost.html); I think it's some improvement of an alphashape algorithm, but I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, function [voronoi_cells](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.voronoi.voronoi_cells.html) in NetworkX returns a dictionary of nodes mapped to each startpoint, where node belongs to a startpoint when node's distance by graph is shortest to a given startpoint

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).